# Можно ли создать selector.xml для обработки поведения сразу нескольких View?

Tags: android

На данный момент у меня есть 3 TextView, и я хочу чтобы при отдельном нажатии на 
любой из них два других меняли свой фон. Я могу это сделать программно, прописав OnClickListener, либо же сделать для каждого TextView свой селектор. Но хотелось бы это как-то объединить..

Т.е. сделать что-то подобное сразу для нескольких вью, но в одном селекторе:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_corners_selected"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/red_corners_unselected"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Вам необходимо имитировать клик или просто меняли фон? Попробуйте на клик одной вызывать performClick() у других.

Comment: имитировать клик. В дальнейшем планирую добавить еще какую-нибудь логику